# divs hide and show

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on a website for a company (my first, except of my own), and i am a little confused. i know that i knew this before, but i have forgot.

i am going to create many different pages on the site and i guess that it´s not a good idea to create one new file for each page.

and i think the best way is to make one "div" for each page, in the index file, and somehow put all of then behind each other, and show one by one when i click on the right thing in the menu... how do i do this?

can i only use CSS or do i need some Java script, and how do i write the code?

very thankful for quick help! :)

Comment: It seems more like you would need a bigger introduction into webdevelopment. Yes CSS and HTML should be used and <div> tags are used to layout your sites. How you add css and javscript is up to the content that you want to show

Comment: You should use PHP. Possibly even a php-based CMS like Drupal (http://drupal.org/), Joomla (http://www.joomla.org/), or WordPress (http://wordpress.org/).

Comment: hm.. okay, in my school we did´nt learned how to use such tools, i just write the code in a program called Aptana Studios...

Comment: 5 comments in a row?! Surf a little bit around on the net. You find a ton of information about Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress... When you use such a CMS you can create a really professional site for the company without wondering about some really technical stuff and focus on the design aspect. Personally I like Drupal the most, but it is probably also the hardest to work with. If you want quick result I recommend you Wordpress.

Comment: This is a completely personal opinion and you're open to (and most likely will) ignore it, but to me, based on what you've said, it seems you're not quite ready to be building a website for another company. This isn't me being condescending, I just feel you shouldn't rush into things and if you feel the task is becoming a burden, don't hesitate to tell the company. It's much better to be honest earlier on than to have the deadline come up and you standing with your tail between your legs in front of the client, who could then talk badly about you to other companies who could have been clients.

Comment: Thanks for your concern :) the thing is, that it is for a very small company that a friend is starting, and it´s not a rush to get it finished. :) and i am starting my trainee on monday (that is a webbdesign-company that mostly works with drupal, so i am going to learn that soon) and i´ve understand from earlier comments, that drupal is good, so i am going to wait few days, until i am starting to learn that, before i continue with the website :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to change the innerHTML of elements.
For example, create a div and give it the ID "myDiv":

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Then, when the user clicks on a button you can change "myDiv"'s innerHTML like this (by calling the function):

```
function show(){
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="html code here";
}
```

I hope I helped :-)

Comment: True, but you should at least note that her approach is inappropriate and will result in a code and maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about making a single HTML page that contains *all* of the content for a company website. It's a bad idea to build a corporate website this way, for several reasons:

- Web browsers expect to navigate through a site that has multiple pages, which is why they have a location bar and forward/back buttons. Your approach breaks both of those.
- This single page would be much larger and take longer to load in users' web browsers.
- The SEO of the page would be poor, because its content would be hard for Google and other spiders to understand semantically. A large page with so much text would look like keyword stuffing to Google and would be penalized.
- It would be difficult to keep such a page organized; making any change to anything would require you to edit a single file, so it would be harder for you to track and/or merge changes to different documents, and much harder for the company to make content changes.
- Lastly, the approach is just *inappropriate*. You are correct that it's not too great to create one static HTML file for every page. But the solution is not to make a single web page; the solution is to use a CMS!

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) is the most popular CMS in the world. It's designed for blogs but can be used for any website. 
[Drupal](http://drupal.org) is a powerful CMS with lots of features you may not need, but it's more modern than Wordpress and may be more visually flexible.

If you don't want to use a full-fledged CMS and you feel like flexing some programming chops, you could try using an out-of-the-box MVC framework like [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), but bear in mind that those will require you to learn a little Ruby or Python.

The main thing is that you should be using server-side templates to solve the problem you have, not client-side JavaScript.

(Some very large websites do use a JavaScript-powered approach to page navigation, but these are usually **web applications** like Twitter. The approach is inappropriate for a corporate web presence.)